# how would i return the address to byte[] offset

Tags: c#

How would I get the correct address returned to byte[] offset im trying to compare each address and then get the one that matches location to return?

```cs
private void getTPOffset(byte[] offset)
{
    byte[] location = Kewi.GetMemory(0xC2482510, 12);
    uint[] HustlinT = { 0xC67BFAE0, 0xC673ACF0, 0xC66899A0, 0xC66A7EF0, 0xC6689AE0, 0xC67BFEA0, 0xC67BF9A0, 0xC67BF860, 0xC67BFD60, 0xC67BF220, 0xC67375E0, 0xC67BF360, 0xC67BF0E0, 0xC66ACFA0, 0xC67839A0, 0xC6782E60 };
    foreach (uint HustlinPOS in HustlinT)
    {
        byte[] comparable = Kewi.GetMemory(HustlinPOS, 12);

        var xz = location.SequenceEqual(comparable);
        if (xz == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("found it");
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: i need it to return the correct address to byte[] offset in funtion

Comment: still offset and return null has errors